# BibTeX "archaeologie" package not working

Tags: biblatex, archaeologie

I am trying to use the bibtex package archaeologie but when I cite I get the error that the citation is undefined on the line. The entry in the .bib file is

```
@Book{Met,
author = {Aristotle},
title = {Metaphysics}, 
language = {greek},
date = {2016},
translator = {C.D.C. Reeve},
publisher = {Hackett},
location = {New York},
shorthand = {\emph{Met.}},
options = {ancient},  
}
```

Where the main text entry is

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{arsclassica} % Modifies the Classic Thesis package
\usepackage[]{classicthesis} % The layout is based on the Classic Thesis style
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{main}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}




\title{\normalfont\spacedallcaps{Paper}} % The article title

%\subtitle{Subtitle} % Uncomment to display a subtitle

\author{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Name}} % The article author(s) - author affiliations need to be specified in the AUTHOR AFFILIATIONS block

\date{} % An optional date to appear under the author(s)
\begin{document}


\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    Some Text in the Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\cite{Met}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that LaTeX can read your .bib file. You also need to actually call the style you defined, like so:

`\usepackage[style=archaeologie,backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Full working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mwe.bib}

@book{Met,
    title        = {Metaphysics},
    author       = {Aristotle},
    location     = {New York},
    publisher    = {Hackett},
    language     = {greek},
    date         = 2016,
    translator   = {C.D.C. Reeve},
    shorthand    = {\emph{Met.}},
    options      = {ancient}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=archaeologie,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

In \cite{Met} Aristotle says that “everyone takes what is called ‘wisdom’ 
(\emph{sophia}) to be blablabla …

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```